# Dynamic theme ant-design prolayout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, umi

I really dont know how to change the theme dynamic in antd pro layout, can someone help me with this problem :(, Thanks you very much.
Currently I am using the theme by exporting file in config/config.ts like this:

```
    export default defineConfig({
     theme: {
    "primary-color": defaultSettings.primaryColor,
  },
})
```